# How to make a verbatim framed text centered on page?

Tags: context

I use this definition make a box with verbatim text inside.

```
  \definetyping[inline][
       numbering=file,
       bodyfont=small,
       lines=yes, 
       indentnext=auto, 
       before={
           \startframedtext[
               location=low,
               align=middle, 
               width=\makeupwidth,
               background=color,
               backgroundcolor=lightgray,
               autowidth=force]},
       after={\stopframedtext}]
```

But I want to center this box in my pages, and evenly indent content of my verbatim inside this box, and not depending of placement of verbatim text inside my .tex file…

I’ve tried almost arguments anywhere, and this box remains at leftside…

Also, is it possible to have any similar configuration to make verbatim text inline with standard text ?

Many thanks